# SSL_CTX_set_verify with NULL verify_callback

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

In openSSL I used function [SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html) with `verify_mode= SSL_VERIFY_PEER` and `verify_callback= NULL` .

What does it mean? The client will verify the server certificates chain or not?

Comment: It will verify the chain with builtin functionality, not with a user specified function.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If the built-in function verify the chain as well, Why should I want to specify my function?

Comment: Because you might want to override the result with a custom validation. For example pinning to specific certificates or CA.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you can add as answer :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reworded answer by [Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich): The optional callback can be used to possibly override the built-in validation.